# Issue Comparing Moments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, momentjs, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I've got the following code that checks to see whether the start date is >= to the end date. Almost every time I compare the two dates when they are identical, the difference between the dates is something less than 0.

Here is my code:

```
var end = $('#job_end').datetimepicker('date');
var start = $('#job_start').datetimepicker('date');

console.log(start);
console.log(end);
console.log(start.diff(end));
console.log(start.isSameOrAfter(end));
```

Here is the output from this code:

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, _d: Wed Jul 25 2018 14:15:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), …}
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, _d: Wed Jul 25 2018 14:15:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), …}
-6
false
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you change it to `console.log(start.toISOString())` and `console.log(end.toISOString())`? That might shed some light.

Comment: @HereticMonkey So doing that printed a start time of `2018-07-18T20:00:00.288Z` and an end time of `2018-07-18T20:00:00.292Z`. I'm using the Tempus Dominus date-time picker. Not sure what to think at the moment.

Comment: That's what I figured, your dates aren't actually the same. @jaredkwright has the right idea in their answer, although you can pass `"days"` (`"minutes"` or `"seconds"`, etc.) as a second parameter to both `diff` and `isSameOrAfter`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey `start.isSameOrAfter(end, "seconds")` works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading your code it looks like you have a difference of something like six milliseconds. Since you are getting the end date first and then the start date, that is probably the execution time of those two lines of code. If you are simply looking to compare the date and not the time as well, check and make sure you are only getting the date and not the time.

Look at using [moment().startOf('day')](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) which will zero the time and you can compare only the day.

Comment: You could probably also use `moment().get('date')` and compare those values.